# warning messages with hikaricp

Tags: java, database-connection, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I am using hikaricp as my database connection pool.  I am closing the connection when I am done with my SQL statement by calling close on the connection which I believe you should return the connection proxy back to the pool . Yet, I see the following warning (not error) message and I have to wonder whether its an issue that needs to be addressed because I'm not cleaning up my connection resources properly.  I am not using a try with resources but using a try catch finally (I close the connection in the finally & I realize that in certain conditions, the finally may actually not get called but it is being called in my case).  any thoughts?

```
2014-09-15 13:59:26,083 WARN c.z.h.p.LeakTask [Hikari Housekeeping Timer (pool wmHikariCp)] Connection leak detection triggered, stack trace follows java.lang.Exception
    at com.abc.test.DBConnPool.getConnection(DBConnPool.java:71)
    at com.abc.test.TestProj.callDB(TestApp.java:30)
    at com.abc.test.TestProj.main(TestApp.java:81)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm whether you are indeed releasing the connection back to the pool?  Can you use try with resources (in addition to increasing threshold as Brett mentioned):

```
try (Connection conn = DBConnectionPool.getConnection(); 
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(preparedQuery);) {
```

and the resultset (because some drivers/databases may not clean out resultset when connection is cleaned though not sure if this is still valid for new drivers/databases but I'm not sure what you are using):

```
    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();) {
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks to both - I noticed an issue with an exception on my side later on that might have been causing the problem (still not confirmed) but I don't see the leak statements anymore when using try with resources

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that you are merely using the connection longer than the leak detection timeout.  The leak detection is a threshold for how long a connection is out of the pool.  Try increasing the threshold to a longer timeout.

Comment: thank you for sharing.  Just to be sure, I'm testing using try with resources just to be sure.  I will increase the threshold as well in a different rest run.